# I'm work in WPF C# project have many dll file, and i want load all dll file with loading home page?

Tags: c#, dll

I'm work in WPF C# project have many dll file, and i want load all dll file with loading login form?

Comment: Anything you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the dll files will get loaded at the point at which you will be building the project.